# chrome extension: On click of parent page like download button trigger the chrome extension/plugin. Is it possible to do?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

```
Manifest.js:

{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "A browser action with a popup that changes the page color",
  "description": "Change the current page color",
  "version":"1.0",
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["popup.js"]
  },
  "icons":{ "64":"icon.png"},
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.mypage.com/*","https://www.mypage.com/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}

content.js:
{
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(document.querySelectorAll('a.icon downloadPdf clickAction'));
```

}

Here I want to trigger my extension based on the parent page click event from "www.mypage.com". Is it possible to trigger the extension without changing the code from mypage.com?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but it seems possible for an extension to do it.  But writing an entire extension is beyond what Stack Overflow does.  Is there a specific point of your extension that you're trying to figure out?

Comment: If you want to show the toolbar popup automatically then it's not possible. The popup is shown only when a user clicks it explicitly. You'll need to use a DOM element instead, there are many examples of doing that.

Comment: Thanks Teepeemm and wOxxOm for replying. In my current application we have option to select multiple documents and download it. These documents are from third party sites.The download logic was written in Applet which is no longer supported by chrome and Firefox. So for that we created the plugin to download the documents which is working absolutely fine. After selecting the documents we have to click the plugin the it starts downloading. Instead of this we have download button in application when user selects docs and clicks the download button it should trigger or open the plugin.

Comment: Let me know weather we can trigger/open the plugin from an event of application